# Why does the id of the datalist option return empty value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been stuck on this datalist for hours now and can't figure out why it returns empty when alerting the selected object (4000 Islands, Laos for example).
Basically I want to return the 'id' attribute of the selected option in the list.

jQuery:

```
$K2 = jQuery.noConflict();
$K2('#submit').on('click',function(){
var g=$K2('#to-selected').val();  
var id = $K2('#to').find('option').attr('id');
alert(id);
return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<td> 
 <input autofocus="" type="text" list="to" id="to-selected" style="width: 145px;"> 
 <datalist id="to"> 
<option id="" value="All"></option>
<option value="4000 Islands, Laos" id="4483"></option>
</datalist> 
</td>
<button id="submit">Test</button>
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the 'All' option as after removal it works fine.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! My JSFiddle can be found here. http://jsfiddle.net/x7oa7wk4/1/

Thanks guys!

Comment: `.attr` will only get the attribute from the *first* item in the collection (which is `All`) ... which id do you actually want to get?

Comment: Oh, hypothetically if i were to get another item in the collection how would i do that? I've been trying so many methods but having luck with none :/

Comment: I may also suggest that you want to do something like `<option value=4483>4000 Islands, Laos</option>` instead

Comment: The problem with this is it appears as "4483 - 4000 Islands, Laos" which is not as appealing to the viewer

Comment: It shouldn't ... only the data between the tags should appear.  The value attribute should not appear.  Maybe there is a typo in your html?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the option which was selected using the value of the input element

```
$K2 = jQuery.noConflict();
$K2('#submit').on('click', function () {
    var g = $K2('#to-selected').val();
    var id = $K2('#to').find('option[value="' + g + '"]').attr('id');
    alert(id);
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6dL3t6gh/)